# How to make npm fail when warning occurs?

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-install

I'm building a npm package and want to detect warnings raised by npm on CI. However, npm's exit status is zero even if warnings are displayed unless there's an error. Is there any option to make `npm install` fail when any warning occurs? Or any other way to detect warnings?

Answer (score 0):

Can you pipe the result of npm into another command to make it fail ?
For instance, with `awk`:

```
yarn | awk '/^warning/ { err = 1} END {exit err}'
```

It will fail if it finds a line starting with warning in the output of `yarn`